# XSLT processing with jaxb for a small transformation performance

Tags: java, performance, jaxb, xslt-1.0

I have a simple transformation. I have a java object to transform into different java object. so i used xslt. jaxb is my processor.

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(
                    new File("conv.xsl"));
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(streamSource);
            JAXBContext jc =JAXBContext.newInstance(Bags.class);
            JAXBSource jAXBSource = new JAXBSource(jc, device);
 jAXBResult = new JAXBResult(JAXBContext.newInstance(LargeBags.class));

            transformer.transform(jAXBSource, jAXBResult);

return result.getResult();
```

Is it ok to do like this in the performance perspective? i can do this with java code. is it a big performance issue? or a good practice? please help me and appreciate your comments. inaddition to that If i have small grouping and calculation is xslt is a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the performance perspective, of course it is not optimal: serialization to xml, transformation of the xml, deserialzation from the xml are costly operations.
But, it sometimes makes sense, if you have a lot of 'similar' classes (for example different field names but matching logic (for example one having user other person field etc), as editing xslt sheets to provide implement conversion is faster and easier to than creating new Adapter class.

But you should definitely speed things up,

Create the jaxbContext once, not at each call, creating JAXB context is very costly operations. for example store it in a map which keys are the class that was used for the JaxbCreation:

```
JAXBContext getContext(Class cls) {
  if (contexts.containsKey(cls)) return contexts.get(cls);
  JAXBContect context = JAXBContext.newInstance(cls);
  contexts.put(cls,context);
  return context;
}
...
JAXBContext jc =getContext(Bags.class);
```

Same trick, with transformers.

Just remember that transformers are not thread safe, so you need to 
synchronize on the transformer before using is if your application is multihreaded.